# Access permission and file path in php

Tags: php, path, permissions

I use a index.php to control the access of pages.

Here is the mechanism:

Index.php redirects the page to search.php; code: `index.php/?page=search` 
the path of search.php is :  `pages/search.php`, search.php includes header.html, body.html etc.

Now in body.html we call search.php using:  `index.php/?page=search` parameter, and body.html includes this code: `index.php/?page=search?query='.quote_replace(addmarks($query)).`  You can see there are two '?'. And it's just this problem.

When i browse search.php, it displays in url: `example.com/?page=search`.

When i click the button in search.php while actually in body.html, it displays in url `example.com/index.php/?query=&search=1`.

In this way, the browse just display page index.php. But i want to display the search result in search.php, and it should display `example.com/?page=search/?query=&search=1`. But you can see `/?page=search` disappears and `/index.php` appears here.

I'm sorry, the condition is complex and i don't describe it very well.  If you couldn't understand it very well, i'll explain.

So, do you have any advice about that?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a string (such as `search/?query=&search=1`) as a URL argument, you need to encode so that it no longer contains *special* charachters such as `?` and `&`. Use the [urlencode() PHP function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for this:

```
urlencode("search/?query=findme&search=1")
```

This will yield the following string, which can be safely included as a URL argument:

```
search%2F%3Fquery%3Dfindme%26search%3D1
```

To build the first string you need to so something similar, i.e. encode all arguments. Here the [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function can be useful, which takes an array with keys and values, encodes all of them and adds the `=` and `&` characters where needed:

```
http_build_query(array("query" => "find&me", "search" => "1"))
```

which yields

```
query=find%26me&search=1
```

Comment: @Wim, Your advice is so good. Do i need to use urlencode and http_build_query together? I'm sorry, i have never used it before. And i have no idea at all right now.

Comment: You could also use `urlencode` for the second case and construct the query string yourself, but `http_build_query` is so much easier. And in any case, you'll need to do two sets of encoding on the same data, because it will also be *decoded* twice (once when the value for *page* is read, and once again when *query* and *search* are read).